# How to start an css effect when website open

Tags: css

I want to start my css3 effect when the website is opened. There is no any special effect in my mind. I just need to learn how can I make active an effect when the page is opened?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

a webkit example I use for fading in all the elements at load:
http://jsfiddle.net/efortis/7PyRL/

```
* {
      -webkit-transition: all .5s;
      -webkit-animation-name: myfading;
      -webkit-animation-duration: .8s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes myfading {
      from {
            opacity: 0;
            -webkit-transition: opacity;
      }
      to {
            opacity: 1;
      }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A general technique would be to give CSS3 transition to the properties you want, then on page load use Javascript `onload` to change those properties. This way it would work across current versions of all browsers.